# xgboost WinError127, windows 10, anaconda

Tags: python, xgboost

i'm trying to install xgboost on my laptop to use in anaconda. After following this link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/entry/Installing_XGBoost_For_Anaconda_on_Windows?lang=en, and after (I think) every step was correctly implemented, when i try to import xgboost in anaconda, i get: [WinError 127] The specified procedure could not be found. I've searched a lot but still haven't manage to find a solution so I'm hoping someone has a light. Thanks

EDIT:
The used code just like in the link

```
import os

mingw_path = 'C:\\Program Files\\mingw-w64\\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\\mingw64\\bin'

os.environ['PATH'] = mingw_path + ';' + os.environ['PATH']

import xgboost as xgb
import numpy as np

data = np.random.rand(5,10) # 5 entities, each contains 10 features
label = np.random.randint(2, size=5) # binary target
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix( data, label=label)

dtest = dtrain

param = {'bst:max_depth':2, 'bst:eta':1, 'silent':1, 'objective':'binary:logistic' }
param['nthread'] = 4
param['eval_metric'] = 'auc'

evallist  = [(dtest,'eval'), (dtrain,'train')]

num_round = 10
bst = xgb.train( param, dtrain, num_round, evallist )

bst.dump_model('dump.raw.txt')
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-2-162883d28707>", line 7, in <module>
    import xgboost as xgb

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.6-py3.6.egg\xgboost\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .core import DMatrix, Booster

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.6-py3.6.egg\xgboost\core.py", line 115, in <module>
    _LIB = _load_lib()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xgboost-0.6-py3.6.egg\xgboost\core.py", line 109, in _load_lib
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(lib_path[0])

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 426, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 127] Impossível localizar o procedimento especificado
```

[image: Error and interface]

Comment: Please post the full traceback

Comment: Sorry, you mean the whole error code?

Comment: Not just the error, but all of the text that comes with the error. That shows where this error originates.

Comment: Just posted both the code and the error

Comment: Eh, the last line of that traceback is giving several different search results. I don't think that is the complete traceback, are you sure that's everything?

Comment: I'll post a image as soon as i find out how

Comment: Not an image, what you updated your question with is fine. I'm not sure this can be answered definitively; maybe this gets you closer? https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/933

Comment: dumb question, but could it be that my python version is 32b and not 64?

Comment: Not a dumb question, that was specifically one of the issues I read while researching this issue.

Comment: Grr, I can't find the issue i read now now but someone did post that upgrading to 64 bit fixed their issue.

Comment: Unistalled everything, download and installing 64, lets hope after the reboot it works!

Answer (score 0):

You dont really have to do all that if you dont want to compile the code. The binaries are (unofficially) available on the internet. Try [this](https://dmenin.wordpress.com/2017/04/05/easiest-way-to-install-xgboost-on-windows-download-binaries-no-need-to-compile/).

EDIT:

Im just re-reading my post. Chances are you are missing the VCOMP140.DLL. Your xgboost installation should be fine (more details at the post).

Comment: Trying it now! Having some issues finding the new python to add to path

Answer (score 0):

You should check this path:

mingw_path = 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-5.3.0-posix-seh-rt_v4-rev0\mingw64\bin'

It's maybe incorrect